# In an Eclipse Run Configuration how to you refer to the username?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've done this in the past, but can't remember how.

What I want to do is pass in my windows login id as a -D variable when running a java process in Eclipse.  I know that you can refer to variables in Run Configurations, but can't see one associated with the login id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a environment variable, e.g.

```
${env_var:USERNAME}
```